# What is the the run time cost of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for i=2 to n
    j=3n
    while j>=1 do 
        j=j/3
```

What would be the run time cost of the given algorithm? Can you please describe the step-wise solution.

Comment: Assuming j=1/3 means j/=3, the code is O(n log n), and not O(n^2).

Comment: @PaulHankin Feel free to answer with that. Question updated

Comment: How about `j=3n`? Should that be `j = 3i`?

Comment: This is obviously homework.  Please show your thoughts on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate time complexity, you usually walk from inner loops to outer loops.

Now the **inner** one is a while loop. It ends when `j < 1`, this is the case after *O(log<sub>3</sub>3n)* steps, or *O(1+log<sub>3</sub> n)* or *O(log<sub>3</sub> n)*. Note that we here use *n*: the loop counter `i` of the outer loop does not play a part here.

The **outer** loop on the other hand is iterated *O(n-1)* times, or thus *O(n)* times and each time, it does the same amount of work: *O(log<sub>3</sub> n)*. So the **total time complexity** is *O(n log<sub>3</sub> n)*.

You can drop the 3 in the log, because *O(log<sub>k</sub>n)* is *O(log n)* for a fixed *k*. So a nicer notation is *O(n log n)*.